# R create file and manage the permission

Tags: r, permissions

I'm using R to create some text file under linux.

I know there's function to manage files like:
- file.create
- file.exists
- file.remove

Now I need to manage the permission.

Is this possible ?
for exemple set the file to be read only by me or by the group?
or chmod to readable by all ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ?system function, it allows you to execute shell commands. For example, try this

```
file.create("bla.r")
system("ls -l bla.r")
system("chmod 777 bla.r")
system("ls -l bla.r")
```